# Styling elements inside slot in Polymer 2.x

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

I have created a polymer element which contains slots. Each slot is intended to be replaced/filled with a HTML element with children and not just plain text. How can I style elements inside the slot and not only the element at top level of the slot? Or maybe, is it wrong to use elements with children for slots?

In example:

**Template file:**

```
<dom-module id="my-element">
  <template>
    <style>
      .class-1 {
        /* Styles here works! */
      }
      .class-1 ::slotted(ul) {
        /* Styles here works! */
      }
      .class-1 ::slotted(ul) a {
        /* Styles here doesn't work */
      }
    </style>
    <div class="class-1">
      <slot name="s1"></slot>
    </div>
  </template>

  <script>
    class MyElement extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'my-element'; }
    }
    window.customElements.define(MyElement.is, MyElement);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

**HTML file:**

```
<my-element>
  <ul slot="s1">
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</my-element>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can only use `::slotted()` to style top-level nodes. This is why it works for `ul` but not for _deeper_ elements. Read [this article](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/shadowdom#stylinglightdom) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, then I think it is not a good idea to use HTML that has child elements as content of slots.

Comment: The preferred way is to style light DOM from the outside. Additional styling of injected HTML should be discouraged, since this increases dependencies between the components.

Comment: @alesc: [That article you referenced](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/shadowdom#stylinglightdom) is a must-read for anyone building web apps today.

Answer (score 3):

Slotted does not allow sub selectors. Which means that

```
.class-1 ::slotted(ul) a
```

simply can not work because the 'a' is a subselection.

Answer (score 0):

try this, but it seems taking effect inside all instance of my-element

```
<my-element><style>li a {color:#333}</style>
  <ul slot="s1">
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</my-element>
```